# Why do we use stringstream to pass data to ofstream in c++

Tags: c++11, io, stream

I happened to find a piece of code like this:

```
// other people's implementation
Obj obj;
stringstream ss;
ofstream outfile("save.pth");
ss.write((char*)obj.data(), obj.size());
outfile << ss.rdbuf();
```

I think directly write to ofstream would be faster, like this:

```
// my approach
Obj obj;
ofstream outfile("save.pth");
outfile.write((char*obj).data(), obj.size());
```

Why some people would like to use stringstream to pass the data?

Comment: Is the code you're asking about really this simple? Or is there more to it, such as writing many objects into `ss` and then only one write into `outfile`, or setting some formatting flags on `ss`?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing - if there were more writes to `ss` I'd assume it's a misguided attempt at defeating the buffering in `ofstream` - perhaps to try and ensure all of the data is written to the file descriptor in one go.  This doesn't work reliably as the call to `write()` might not accept all of the data in one call.